# Building a polyhedron from an extruded polygon

Tags: c++, geometry, computational-geometry

I thought this should be straightforward, but I've searched for quite some time and did not good find examples:

I have polygon type like in geojson: simple type OGR polygon with a vector of rings, where the outer ring is the shell and other rings define holes.

The points constituting rings are given in 3D, though you can assume the polygon is flat but using a z.

Now I want to create a polyhedron from that polygon with some given extrusion. What algorithm do I need to apply?

Answer (score 2):

For each edge `(v1, v2)` of the input polygon, you create a quadrilateral for the output polyhedron with the coordinates:

```
v1.x v1.y v1.z
v2.x v2.y v2.z
v2.x v2.y v2.z + extrudeHeight
v1.x v1.y v1.z + extrudeHeight
```

Finally, add the base polygon (including its holes) in reverse order with `z` shifted by `extrudeHeight`.

If your polygons are oriented consistently, your output polyhedron will also have a consistent orientation.

I assumed that your polygon has constant z-coordinates. If this is not what you meant, leave a comment.